# Disable IDA Downloading Symbols Automatically

Tags: ida

How can I disable IDA Downloading symbols? It pops up everytime I attach to a remote process. It is really annoying.

[image]

Comment: It's just helping you debugging your program. It downloads the symbols so you can debug the dependencies easier. Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: If you really want to disable it, disconnect from the internet / block internet access of IDA, or find some setting to stop the download (I'm on a phone without IDA now)

Comment: Because I am debugging an mobile application that is heavily obfuscated and has lots of anti debug/tracing/hooking techniques. Sometime IDA attaches to a remote process and waiting for downloading symbols to long, it makes the application stop. So that why I want to temporary disable this feature.

Comment: @raspiduino I have already searched the internet for an option disabling the downloading symbols but got nothing.